# Query which duplicates some lines

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database which looks like this and I would like to retrieve some data : 
[image]

And when I do a query to retrieve all things, I got this response :

```
+----------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------------+--+
| id_stats |            nom_stats             | id_equipement | id_equipement | id_stats | id_elements |  |
+----------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------------+--+
|        3 | PO                               |             1 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       25 | Maîtrise Distance                |             1 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       29 | Points de Vie                    |             1 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       33 | Résistance Élémentaire Aléatoire |             1 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       12 | Esquive                          |             8 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       13 | Tacle                            |             8 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       15 | Parade                           |             8 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       22 | Résistance Feu                   |             8 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       23 | Résistance Eau                   |             8 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       29 | Points de Vie                    |             8 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 8             | 32       | 1           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 15            | 32       | 1           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 8             | 32       | 3           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 15            | 32       | 3           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 8             | 32       | 4           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 15            | 32       | 4           |  |
|        1 | PA                               |            15 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|        2 | PM                               |            15 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|        4 | % Coup Critique                  |            15 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       24 | Résistance Élémentaire           |            15 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       27 | Maîtrise Zone                    |            15 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       29 | Points de Vie                    |            15 | NULL          | NULL     | NULL        |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 8             | 32       | 1           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 15            | 32       | 1           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 8             | 32       | 3           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 15            | 32       | 3           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 8             | 32       | 4           |  |
|       32 | Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire   |             8 | 15            | 32       | 4           |  |
+----------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------------+----------+-------------+--+
```

With this query :

```
SELECT * FROM stuff S
INNER JOIN stuff_equipement ES ON S.id_stuff = ES.id_stuff
INNER JOIN equipement_stats SA ON SA.id_equipement = ES.id_equipement
INNER JOIN stats ST ON ST.id_stats = SA.id_stats
LEFT JOIN stuff_equipement_stats_elements STA ON STA.id_stats = ST.id_stats
```

the data in 'stuff_equipement_stats_elements' are :

[image]

So I do not really understand why I have duplicate data. When you look at the response I got, I should only have 3 entries "Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire" per id_equipement. For a defined "id_equipement" I also have other entries from entity  "stuff_equipement_stats_elements" whether the id_equipement is the same or not...

I have already tried some other queries for example change the last line of my initial query by :

```
LEFT JOIN stuff_equipement_stats_elements STA ON SA.id_equipement = STA.id_equipement
```

But now I have the good amount of "Maîtrise Élémentaire Aléatoire" but 4 last lines are filled when they should not exist because I haven't filled them yet, and other duplicates data now.

**EDIT :**

stuff has some equipement

equipement has some statistics

statistics has some elements but only for certain statistics

for stastitics who have elements(earth, wind, fire, water), you can choose what elements the stuff have.

To know which elements a "stuff" chose you must know the stuff you are on, the equipement concerned and stat concerned because it's only for some stats and finally the elements he chose, I made a table with multiple primary key

```
id_stuff | id_equipement | id_stats | id_elements
```

Comment: Please put your output in the question instead of a picture.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Can anyone here read that tiny image text?)

Comment: I can, barely.  I'd replace the French too.

Comment: Can you please tell us exactly what data is in all the tables involved so we can recreate and solve?

Comment: And btw it looks from your diagram that you should be joining 'stuff_equipement_stats_elements' directly to 'stuff'...

Comment: Sorry I'm not used to that and I don't know how to put a clear table to give you the response. Also, what do you mean by data in? The way they act? I edited my post, please tell me if this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Here's a link that includes other links to tools that make it easier to post questions on forums. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by hiding duplicate lines with those WHERE clause :

```
AND ES.id_equipement = OS.id_equipement OR OS.id_equipement IS NULL
```

That way, all duplicates lines go away.